# react-daterange-picker display previous month on a side by side view

Tags: reactjs, react-daterange-picker

I am working with this [react date range calendar plugin](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker) I have two months side by side using `showDoubleView={true}` It is displaying the current month + the following one. Which is the default behavior

But now I want to display the **previous month + the current month**. How can I specify it?

here's a sample of my code

```
<DateRangePicker
                onChange={handleValueChange}
                value={calendarValue}
                closeCalendar={true}
                format={'dd-MM-y'}
                showDoubleView={true}
                minDetail={'year'}
                showNeighboringMonth={true}
                selectRange={true}
            />
```

I tried to set `activeStartDate={new Date(2021/2/1)}` but the calendar displays the year 1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't forget to put quotation marks around your date. Maybe this is the problem of 1970 year.
For example:

```
new Date(2021/2/1) // outputs Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:01 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

```
new Date('2021/2/1') // outputs Mon Feb 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Comment: Indeed it was missing the quotation marks. It works But now that I look better in the docs https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar#props they are passing as isolated paramenters  year, month, day